# How to embed calendar.google.com into a site without APIs

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, calendar

I need to embed calendar.google.com in a site, unfortunately I can't use the apis because they don't have the new material design, and google is blocking all the requests with the xframe-option. So I was wondering if there's a way to bypass it or use another alternative. Thanks all

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

According to a [post](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/calendar/YDjVe6ivOpc/KHJdpBH9AgAJ) on Google's Product Forums, there's no Material version yet:

> Currently, there isn't an update for an embedded calendar. I'd appreciate your feedback in this regards. Will keep you posted once I have an update.

Comment: You are right sorry, I meant google calendar's iframe that allows you to embed it directly on your site; It has the old style and is not graphically updated. I surely can create my own calendar with the APIs but is a work (for me) too complex and long for what I have to do